# Reference a previous row value from my resultset in LAG function using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do use I LAG to use the previous row value for this row?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PatientID, ReferralPatientID, ReferralDate,
    MAX(DischargeDateCalc) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY ReferralPatientID ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) MaxDate,
    MAX(DischargeDateCalc) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY ReferralPatientID ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) PriorMax,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX( DischargeDateCalc) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY ReferralPatientID ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) IS NULL
            THEN CONCAT('MAST',ReferralPatientID)
        WHEN ReferralDate > MAX(DischargeDateCalc) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY ReferralPatientID ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
            THEN CONCAT('MAST', ReferralPatientID)
        ELSE CONCAT('MAST', LAG(MasterEpisode, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Pax ORDER BY RPID ASC))
    END AS MasterEpisode
FROM 
    cte_episodes ep
ORDER BY
    PatientID, ReferralPatientID
```

Screenshot of the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUoE4.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf5tN.png)

But I get the error:

> Invalid column name 'MasterEpisode'

in the `ELSE ...` line

How do I get the system to recognise `MasterEpisode` as a valid column name from the result set?

Comment: Please don't post images... we have everything we need without it

Comment: You are trying to reference the column name of the column within the calculation of the columns values? How can that work? I have no idea what that is attempting to do.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results (as table markdown **not** images).

Comment: Typically if you want to reference a calculated column again, you either create it in a `cross apply` or you use a sub-query. But its far from clear what you need here.